# How to improve performance on query that uses OUTER APPLY

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In order to get a "Description" column for an entity, I need to join multiple tables. Inner joining was in the beginning sufficient, but now requirements have changed, and I need to get multiple rows from the table that holds the "Description" column, so I created a Table-Valued function instead.

The problem is that the query is performing alot worse. When inner joins were used, it took 1 second, now it takes 30 seconds.

How can I optimize performance?

I am aware that using outer apply returns more rows than inner join.

I tried adding AGR_LINE_NO and Meta_IsCurrent as an clustered index on the AGREEMENT_LINE table, but that only improved performance on the original query.

Below is the original query, the new one, the function, and the execution plans.

**Original query:**

```
SELECT TOP 10000 
OBJECT_TYPE,
SEQ_NO,
O.AGR_LINE_NO,
SHORT_DESC,
C02,
C03,
C04,
C05,
C07,
C10,
C52,
N05,
N04,
N02,
N19,
N01,
X.[Description]     AS CarConcept,
O.[Timestamp]       AS OBJ_TIMESTAMP,
O.Record_Timestamp  AS OBJ_RECORD_TIMESTAMP,
X.RECORD_TIMESTAMP  AS X_RECORD_TIMESTAMP

  FROM [Archive].[TIA_TIA_OBJECT] O

  INNER JOIN [Archive].[TIA_TIA_AGREEMENT_LINE] A   
  ON A.AGR_LINE_NO = O.Agr_Line_No

  INNER JOIN [Archive].[TIA_TIA_PRODUCT_LINE] PL 
  ON PL.PRODUCT_LINE_ID = A.PRODUCT_LINE_ID AND PL.PRODUCT_LINE_VER_NO = A.PRODUCT_LINE_VER_NO

  INNER JOIN [Archive].[TIA_TIA_TARIFF_STRUCTURE] TS 
  ON PL.TARIFF_TYPE_LIST_VER = TS.[VERSION] AND PL.PRODUCT_LINE_ID = TS.PRODUCT_LINE_ID

  INNER JOIN [Archive].[TIA_TIA_TARIFF_CODES] TC 
  ON TC.PRODUCT_LINE_ID = PL.PRODUCT_LINE_ID AND TC.[TYPE] = TS.[TYPE] AND TC.[VERSION] = TS.TYPE_VERSION  

  INNER JOIN [Archive].[TIA_TIA_XLA_PE_REFERENCE] X
  ON TC.[TYPE] = X.Table_Name AND PL.PRODUCT_LINE_ID = X.ID AND TC.[VERSION] = X.[VERSION] AND TC.CODE = X.[CODE]

  WHERE O.OBJECT_TYPE = 'BIO01'

  AND 
  TC.[TYPE] =    
  CASE WHEN O.C52 IS NOT NULL 
      THEN 'XTARIFTYPE'
      ELSE  'ART'
  END

  AND X.[Language] = 'DK'

  AND 
  X.Code =
  CASE WHEN O.C52 IS NOT NULL 
      THEN O.C52
      ELSE  O.C02
  END

  AND O.Meta_IsCurrent = 1 
  AND A.Meta_IsCurrent = 1
  AND PL.Meta_IsCurrent = 1
  AND TS.Meta_IsCurrent = 1
  AND TC.Meta_IsCurrent = 1
  AND X.Meta_IsCurrent = 1
```

**New query:**

```
SELECT TOP 10000
OBJECT_TYPE,
SEQ_NO,
O.AGR_LINE_NO,
SHORT_DESC,
C02,
C03,
C04,
C05,
C07,
C10,
C52,
N05,
N04,
N02,
N19,
N01,
carConcept.CodeDescription      AS CarConcept,
O.[Timestamp]       AS OBJ_TIMESTAMP,
O.Record_Timestamp  AS OBJ_RECORD_TIMESTAMP,
carConcept.RECORD_TIMESTAMP AS X_RECORD_TIMESTAMP

  FROM [Archive].[TIA_TIA_OBJECT] O

  INNER JOIN [Archive].[TIA_TIA_AGREEMENT_LINE] A   
  ON A.AGR_LINE_NO = O.Agr_Line_No

  INNER JOIN [Archive].[TIA_TIA_PRODUCT_LINE] PL 
  ON PL.PRODUCT_LINE_ID = A.PRODUCT_LINE_ID AND PL.PRODUCT_LINE_VER_NO = A.PRODUCT_LINE_VER_NO

  OUTER APPLY Staging.ufnGetCodeDescription(PL.PRODUCT_LINE_ID, PL.PRODUCT_LINE_VER_NO, PL.TARIFF_TYPE_LIST_VER,
  CASE WHEN O.C52 IS NOT NULL 
      THEN 'XTARIFTYPE'
      ELSE  'ART'
  END, 
  CASE WHEN O.C52 IS NOT NULL 
      THEN O.C52
      ELSE  O.C02
  END) carConcept

  WHERE O.OBJECT_TYPE = 'BIO01'

  AND O.Meta_IsCurrent = 1 
  AND A.Meta_IsCurrent = 1
  AND PL.Meta_IsCurrent = 1
```

**The Table-Valued function:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [Staging].[ufnGetCodeDescription]
(
    @ProductLineId as nvarchar(20),
    @ProductLineVersion as decimal(10,4),
    @TariffTypeListVer as decimal(10,4),
    @Type as nvarchar(20),
    @Code as nvarchar(20)
)
RETURNS @returntable TABLE
(
    CodeDescription nvarchar(100) NOT NULL, 
    Record_Timestamp datetime2 NOT NULL
)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @CodeDescription as nvarchar(200) 
    DECLARE @Record_Timestamp as datetime2

    SELECT 
    @CodeDescription = X.[Description], 
    @Record_Timestamp = X.RECORD_TIMESTAMP

    FROM  [Archive].[TIA_TIA_TARIFF_STRUCTURE] TS 

    INNER JOIN [Archive].[TIA_TIA_TARIFF_CODES] TC 
    ON TC.PRODUCT_LINE_ID = @ProductLineId AND TC.[TYPE] = TS.[TYPE] AND TC.[VERSION] = TS.TYPE_VERSION  

    INNER JOIN [Archive].[TIA_TIA_XLA_PE_REFERENCE] X
    ON TC.[TYPE] = X.Table_Name AND @ProductLineId = X.ID AND TC.[VERSION] = X.[VERSION] AND TC.CODE = X.[CODE]

    WHERE 

    TS.PRODUCT_LINE_ID = @ProductLineId
    AND
    TS.[VERSION] = @TariffTypeListVer

    AND TS.CLASS = 'CODE'

    AND TC.[TYPE] = @Type
    AND TC.Code = @Code

    AND X.[Language] = 'DK'

    AND TS.Meta_IsCurrent = 1
    AND TC.Meta_IsCurrent = 1
    AND X.Meta_IsCurrent = 1

    IF @CodeDescription IS NOT NULL AND @Record_Timestamp IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        INSERT @returntable
        SELECT @CodeDescription, @Record_Timestamp
    END;
    RETURN;
END
```

**Execution plan original query:**

https://pastebin.com/3j9G1rSi

[image]

**Execution plan new query:**

https://pastebin.com/uAADwuU6

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tables that I am joining on in the function (TIA_TIA_TARIFF_STRUCTURE, TIA_TIA_TARIFF_CODES, TIA_TIA_XLA_PE_REFERENCE) did not have proper indexes.

I thought that it was not necessary since they contained approximately 3K, 17K and 22K rows.

Putting a clustered index on the tables that [Staging].[ufnGetCodeDescription] is joining reduced performance from 30 seconds to 5-6 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Using the OUTER APPLY you in fact execute you function (and the SELECT in the function) for each row.

Instead I would suggest to move the function calls out of the FROM/WHERE. Just retrieve all the necessary columns/

The idea is to select necessary columns first and call the function to relatively small rowset where all the filters are already applied.

```
SELECT
    sub.*,
    carConcept.*
FROM (the new query except the OUTER APPLY) sub
  OUTER APPLY Staging.ufnGetCodeDescription(SUB.PRODUCT_LINE_ID, SUB.PRODUCT_LINE_VER_NO, SUB.TARIFF_TYPE_LIST_VER,
  CASE WHEN SUB.C52 IS NOT NULL 
      THEN 'XTARIFTYPE'
      ELSE  'ART'
  END, 
  CASE WHEN SUB.C52 IS NOT NULL 
      THEN SUB.C52
      ELSE  SUB.C02
  END) carConcept
```

OR you can still use INNER JOINs. If the INNER JOIN returns multiple rows add GROUP BY logic to return first values.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It didnt fix the performance issue, but is usefull in general.